# CollectionView cell hidden behind element

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scroll, uicollectionview

I'm making this chat app and I have a problem which I hope someone can help me with. In the image that you can see I have a collection view of all the messages in the chat, the problem here is that there is one more message which you can not see in the image since it is hidden behind the input text and button. If I hold the mouse and scroll down I can see it but when I let go it bounces back to where I can't see the last message. I do not know what the problem is so I really don't know what code to share with you, but maybe you know what the problem may be and what part of code has to be fixed?

**Image:**

[image]

**Edit:** code for constraints:

```
private func setupInputComponents()
{
    let topBorderView = UIView()
    topBorderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

    messageInputContainerView.addSubview(inputTextField)
    messageInputContainerView.addSubview(sendButton)
    messageInputContainerView.addSubview(topBorderView)

    messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0][v1(60)]|", views: inputTextField, sendButton)
    messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: inputTextField)
    messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: sendButton)

    messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: topBorderView)
    messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(0.5)]", views: topBorderView)
}
```

also, this is in viewDidLoad:

```
    view.addSubview(messageInputContainerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: messageInputContainerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(48)]", views: messageInputContainerView)

    bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageInputContainerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)

    setupInputComponents()
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from storyboard? Just click on collectionView so we can preview constraint. My first guess is that you set wrong constraint for the collectionView's bottom.

Comment: Constraints are written in code, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JHGoEg41IJNk9QQ_hPWcyRo) Youtube tutorial, It's using an older version of Swift so everything is not exactly the same in the current version.

Comment: Is your enter message view simply on top of the collection view?

Comment: What is the value of bottom constraint and where is it anchored? You should post constraints code to the post. Sorry but I don't have time to search through videos to figure this out.

Comment: @ZassX I just added the code for constraints, did not mean for you to watch through a tutorial, just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @AuRis thats what it looks like right? I dont know though, I don't think so? Check out my edit in the question, maybe you can see there.

Comment: Oh no problem man. I am noticing there aren't any constraints for collectionview. Can you provide some code for that? For now it looks like the input view is just put on top of the collectionview, that is why the messages that are under aren't visible.

Comment: You should create a vertical spacing constraint between your "enter message view" and the collection view. Set your message view content resistance priority higher than that of collectionView.

Comment: @AuRis How do I do that?

Comment: In your interface builder hover on collectionView press "Control" key + mouse click and drag your cursor to the other view. You will see the dialog with the constraints, select "Vertical Spacing". Later adjust the constant of the constraint.

Comment: @AuRis I'm using constraints in code, check out my edit in the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is better solution to add textview and button as viewcontroller accessory view

If you have seen  native Messaging  app of ios you dismiss keyboard with swipe gesture interactively.
with that your problem also will be solved as we are not adding textview and button to the uiview as subview it will be worked as accessory view of view controller

Step 1: (Optional)

Goto Storybaord select collection view and on property list change Keyboard dismiss mode to Dismiss interactively

[image]

and also make your collection view to fill the entire screen (don't add space for your textField and send button )

Step 2:

In your view controller add following properties on top

```
var viewAcc: UIView?
var sendButton: UIButton!
var inputTextField: UITextField!

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return viewAcc
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

In ViewDidLoad Method add following code for init view and add textField and send button

```
    viewAcc = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    inputTextField = UITextField (frame: CGRect(x:8, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44 ))
    inputTextField.inputAccessoryView = nil
    inputTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    inputTextField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = .white
    viewAcc?.addSubview(inputTextField);

    let topBorderView = UIView()
    topBorderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(0.5)]", views: topBorderView)

    sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(sendButton)

    inputTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))
```

Now run the app you can see the textField and button at bottom and you can also see your full collection view. and you can dismiss keyboard with just hold and swipe down

Hope it is helpful

Comment: How do I get the sendButton to appear?

Comment: @random1234 it is not part of uiview contorller accessory view so it will be always on top so you won't face any scroll issue of your collection view

Comment: What? I'm wondering how I get the sendButton to appear next to the textField, like it was before.

Comment: @random1234 Thank you also try this out awesome thing `yourCollectionviewObject.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive`

Answer (score 0):

Improved code on ios swift 4.2 show the text buttons . As when typing in above code sendButton automatically hides so i modified it   to remain consistent

```
collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    viewAcc = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    inputTextField = UITextField (frame: CGRect(x:8, y:0, width:400, height: 44 ))
    inputTextField.inputAccessoryView = nil
    inputTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    inputTextField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = .white
    viewAcc?.addSubview(inputTextField);

    let topBorderView = UIView()
    topBorderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsInViews(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsInViews(format: "V:|[v0(0.5)]", views: topBorderView)

    sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addmessage), for: .touchUpInside)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(sendButton)

    inputTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsInViews(format: "H:|-4-[v0][v1(60)]|", views: inputTextField,sendButton)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsInViews(format: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: inputTextField)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsInViews(format: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: sendButton)
```